# How to call managed DLL (with GUI) from VC++?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll

I have a legacy (non-.NET) VC++ project which needs to use some new components written in WPF/WCF. I created a C# DLL to wrap the calls to WPF/WCF. As a test, I created a C# client to use this DLL and everything seems to work fine.

Then, I followed the article [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/828736) to create the VC++ console app for testing. However, the GUI doesn't come out. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#import "..\PreDll.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

using namespace PreDll;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ILicPtr pILic(__uuidof(Lic));

    VARIANT_BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    long lResult = 0;

    pILic->Check(&bResult);

    pILic->Add(3, 5, &lResult);

    wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

For verification, I also included the Add method from Microsoft sample which is working fine. However, my function call to Check supposes to pop up a dialog and it never happens. What did I miss?

Comment: "It doesn't come out" is not an appropriate problem description.  Do *not* use raw_interfaces_only, that just lets you ignore the **required** error checking.  The return value of these methods is HRESULT, you must verify it.  The value tells you what is wrong, IErrorInfo gives you the error message.

Comment: @Hans Passant If I remove raw_interfaces_only, I can't even compile. The error is "...ILic::Add' : function does not take 3 arguments"

Comment: You get the friendly wrappers, long lResult = pILic->Add(3, 5);  Look at the .tli file.

Answer (score 0):

try to unregister and register

```
> regsvcs /u myDLL.dll

> regasm myDLL.dll /unregister

> regasm myDll.dll /tlb:myDLL.tlb /codebase


//i hope you have both of them in same interface
public interface ILicPtr
{
    int Add(int x, int y);
    int Check();
};
```

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work. Can you please explain why unregister and register could solve this problem? To the interface, yes, I have all methods in the same interface.

Comment: as you said add() works properly, I suggest you to call check() in your C# add function so it gets call when you execute add() in c++ or may be write log to file

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the debugger to verify that you can step from the C++ _tmain routine into your .net routines? Does the code return cleanly, or is some kind of exception raised? Debugging should be seamless if the two projects are in the same solution.

Can you post the C# code that shows the popup?

If can step from C++ into C# no problem, and no weird exceptions happen, then I would look at the setup of your UI engine.

Comment: I can't step from C++ into C# because I can't reference the C# dll directly, I had to convert it to TLB first and then import TLB in C++ project.